WooCommerce Bookings: Disable specific shipping method based on selected booking dates
I'm working on a WooCommerce project where I need to disable a specific shipping method (flat_rate:13) based on the selected booking dates. Specifically, I want to disable the shipping method if the start or end date of the booking falls on Tuesday, Thursday, Saturday, Sunday.
I've attempted to implement a solution using a combination of PHP and JavaScript, but I'm encountering some issues with the implementation.
Here's the approach I've tried:
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_disable_shipping_for_bookings', 10, 2);

function custom_disable_shipping_for_bookings($rates, $package) {
 
  $booking_data = WC()->session->get('booking_data');

  if (empty($booking_data)) {
    return $rates; // No booking data, return all rates
  }

 
  $start_date = new DateTime($booking_data['start_date']);
  $end_date = new DateTime($booking_data['end_date']);

 
  $flat_rate_id = array_search('flat_rate:13', array_column($rates, 'id'));
  if ($flat_rate_id === false) {
    return $rates; // 'flat_rate:13' method not found, return all rates
  }

 
  for ($date = $start_date; $date <= $end_date; $date->modify('+1 day')) {
    $day_of_week = $date->format('l'); 
    if (in_array($day_of_week, array('Tuesday', 'Thursday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'))) {
      
      unset($rates[$flat_rate_id]);
      break; 
    }
  }

  return $rates;
}




